# Обработка формы пола (регистрация на сайте)

Tags: jquery, регистрация

Здравствуйте!

Есть форма:

```js
var fail = false;
var warn = false;
//IF FAIL=true
function failColor(obj) {
  "use strict";
  $(obj).css("background-color", "#831F21");
}
//IF FAIL=false
function successColor(obj) {
  "use strict";
  $(obj).css("background-color", "#238822");
}
//FOR EMAIL START
$("#email").blur(function() {
  "use strict";
  if ($(this).val() !== '') {
    var mailCheck = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/i;

    if (mailCheck.test($(this).val())) {
      successColor($(this));
      fail = "";
      $("#mailErr").text(fail);
    } else {
      failColor($(this));
      fail = "Incorrect Email.";
      $("#mailErr").text(fail);
    }
  } else if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
    failColor($(this));
    fail = "Email field is required to be filled!";
    $("#mailErr").text(fail);
  }
});
//FOR EMAIL END

//FOR NAME START
$("#name").blur(function() {
  "use strict";
  if ($(this).val().length <= 4) {
    failColor($(this));
    fail = "Nickname has to be longer than 4 symbols!";
    $("#nameErr").text(fail);
  } else if ($(this).val().length >= 32) {
    failColor($(this));
    fail = "Your nickname should be less than 32 symbols.";
    $("#nameErr").text(fail);
  } else {
    successColor($(this));
    fail = "";
    $("#nameErr").text(fail);

  }
});
//FOR NAME END

//FOR PASSWORD START
$("#password").blur(function() {
  "use strict";
  if ($(this).val().length <= 4) {
    failColor($(this));
    fail = "Your password is too short.";
    $("#passErr").text(fail);
  } else if ($(this).val().length >= 4 && $(this).val().length <= 7) {
    $("#password").css("background-color", "#C16516");
    warn = "Your password is OK but we suggest to make it a little bit longer.";
    $("#passErr").text(warn);
    $("#passErr").css("color", "#C16516");
  } else if ($(this).val().length >= 34) {
    failColor($(this));
    fail = "Your password is too long. The length is 4-34 symbols.";
    $("#passErr").text(fail);
  } else {
    successColor($(this));
    fail = "";
    $("#passErr").text(fail);
  }
});
//FOR PASSWORD END

//SUBMIT START
$("#register").click(function() {
  "use strict";
  if (fail === false || fail === "") {
    return true;
  } else {
    $("#submissionErr").text("Register failed. Please check the red fields.");
    return false;
  }
});
//SUBMIT END
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */


/* Main form */

div.forma {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.forma h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #DBD7D7
}

.register {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border: 3px outset #7A0EB3;
  background-color: #832ACA;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 1px 2px rgba(26, 26, 26, .7);
  text-align: center;
}

.register label {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 5px auto 5px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #DBDBDB;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.register input {
  display: inline;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5px auto 20px;
  border: 3px outset rgba(137, 20, 167, 1.00);
  color: #0E2CC6;
  font-size: 0.99em;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
}

.register p {
  margin: -10px auto 5px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #AC0C0F;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}

#register {
  border: 2px outset #2619A3;
  background-color: #1709CD;
  color: #F7EFEF;
  width: 23%;
  border-radius: 30%
}

div.gender {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

div.gender input {
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="forma">
  <h2>
    <?php echo $htext?>
  </h2>
  <form class="register">
    <label>Welcome to registration page! Type in required values into these fields to register.</label><br/>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" />
    <p id="mailErr"></p>
    <label for="name">Nickname</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NICKNAME" id="name" />
    <p id="nameErr"></p>
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    <div class="gender">
      <b style="float: left; color:#03A9FF">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"/>
      <i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i> Male</b>
      <b style="float: right; color: #D805CD">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"/>
      <i class="fa fa-female" aria-hidden="true"></i> Female</b>
    </div> <br/><br/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" id="password" />
    <p id="passErr"></p>
    <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" name="register" />
    <p id="submissionErr"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Как видите есть проверка пола (*муж, жен*), и мне его надо включить, как обязательный параметр в скрипте после комментария `//SUBMISSION START`, и если пол не выбран, то в `else` вывести в поле `submissionErr` вот такое:

```
$("#submissionErr").text("Please select your gender");
```

Заранее благодарен. И еще если в скрипте найдете немного "быдлокода", то не ругайте сильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var fail = false;
var warn = false;
//IF FAIL=true
function failColor(obj) {
  "use strict";
  $(obj).css("background-color", "#831F21");
}
//IF FAIL=false
function successColor(obj) {
  "use strict";
  $(obj).css("background-color", "#238822");
}
//FOR EMAIL START
$("#email").blur(function() {
  "use strict";
  if ($(this).val() !== '') {
    var mailCheck = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/i;

    if (mailCheck.test($(this).val())) {
      successColor($(this));
      fail = "";
      $("#mailErr").text(fail);
    } else {
      failColor($(this));
      fail = "Incorrect Email.";
      $("#mailErr").text(fail);
    }
  } else if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
    failColor($(this));
    fail = "Email field is required to be filled!";
    $("#mailErr").text(fail);
  }
});
//FOR EMAIL END

//FOR NAME START
$("#name").blur(function() {
  "use strict";
  if ($(this).val().length <= 4) {
    failColor($(this));
    fail = "Nickname has to be longer than 4 symbols!";
    $("#nameErr").text(fail);
  } else if ($(this).val().length >= 32) {
    failColor($(this));
    fail = "Your nickname should be less than 32 symbols.";
    $("#nameErr").text(fail);
  } else {
    successColor($(this));
    fail = "";
    $("#nameErr").text(fail);

  }
});
//FOR NAME END

//FOR PASSWORD START
$("#password").blur(function() {
  "use strict";
  if ($(this).val().length <= 4) {
    failColor($(this));
    fail = "Your password is too short.";
    $("#passErr").text(fail);
  } else if ($(this).val().length >= 4 && $(this).val().length <= 7) {
    $("#password").css("background-color", "#C16516");
    warn = "Your password is OK but we suggest to make it a little bit longer.";
    $("#passErr").text(warn);
    $("#passErr").css("color", "#C16516");
  } else if ($(this).val().length >= 34) {
    failColor($(this));
    fail = "Your password is too long. The length is 4-34 symbols.";
    $("#passErr").text(fail);
  } else {
    successColor($(this));
    fail = "";
    $("#passErr").text(fail);
  }
});
//FOR PASSWORD END

//SUBMISSION START
$("#register").click(function() {
  if( !$('[name="gender"]:checked').length ){
    $("#submissionErr").text("Please select your gender");
  };
});
//SUBMISSION END

//SUBMIT START
$("#register").click(function() {
  "use strict";
  if (fail === false || fail === "") {
    return true;
  } else {
    $("#submissionErr").text("Register failed. Please check the red fields.");
    return false;
  }
});
//SUBMIT END
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */


/* Main form */

div.forma {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.forma h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #DBD7D7
}

.register {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border: 3px outset #7A0EB3;
  background-color: #832ACA;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 1px 2px rgba(26, 26, 26, .7);
  text-align: center;
}

.register label {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 5px auto 5px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #DBDBDB;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.register input {
  display: inline;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5px auto 20px;
  border: 3px outset rgba(137, 20, 167, 1.00);
  color: #0E2CC6;
  font-size: 0.99em;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
}

.register p {
  margin: -10px auto 5px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #AC0C0F;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}

#register {
  border: 2px outset #2619A3;
  background-color: #1709CD;
  color: #F7EFEF;
  width: 23%;
  border-radius: 30%
}

div.gender {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

div.gender input {
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="forma">
  <h2>
    <?php echo $htext?>
  </h2>
  <form class="register">
    <label>Welcome to registration page! Type in required values into these fields to register.</label><br/>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" />
    <p id="mailErr"></p>
    <label for="name">Nickname</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NICKNAME" id="name" />
    <p id="nameErr"></p>
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    <div class="gender">
      <b style="float: left; color:#03A9FF">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"/>
      <i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i> Male</b>
      <b style="float: right; color: #D805CD">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"/>
      <i class="fa fa-female" aria-hidden="true"></i> Female</b>
    </div> <br/><br/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" id="password" />
    <p id="passErr"></p>
    <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" name="register" />
    <p id="submissionErr"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```